# what function has zeros at the singularities of the hyperbolic tangent function?

Tags: trigonometry, roots, singularity, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

I'm completely drawing a blank for some reason.

The function tanh(x) has poles when -I*z/Pi-1/2 is equal to an integer. That is, in the sequence

$i/2\pi\, \left( 2\,n+1 \right)$

There must be some standard trig function that has as roots (like the way sin(2*Pi*n) has roots at each n) at the points (I*(1/2))*Pi*(2*n+1) so that

tanh(x)*f(x) would be an entire function rather than merely meromorphic

Comment: Well $\tanh(x) = \sinh(x)/\cosh(x)$, so $\tanh(x)\cosh(x) = \sinh(x)$ is entire. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, that does fit the bill as far as cancelling the poles in the denominator sine tanh(x)*cosh(x)=sinh(x)  however I forgot to mention that I was wanting the resulting function to stay bounded between -1 and 1 and sinh does not.